# How do I get my accordion to load with all the menus closed?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I'm trying to follow the example here

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

I have placed a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/gqe7g/

Loading behavior is strange.  It shows Menu1 then collapses it then shows Menu2 and Menu3.  I would like everything to open collapsed.  I have tried the following without success

```
$('#accordion').collapse({hide: true})
```

Comment: See this: Collapse all on load Issue - https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3070

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Replacing

```
$(".collapse").collapse();
$('#accordion').collapse({hide: true})
```

with:

```
$('#collapseOne').collapse("hide");
```

should do the trick. I think the first one is toggled on by default and this one line switches it off.

Comment: its actually $('#collapse').collapse("hide"); this does the trick

Comment: This will still show the collapse animation after DOM is ready, which makes it look like a hack.
Change all tabs like <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse"> will collapse all tabs on page load.

Answer (score 159):

From the doc:

> If you'd like it to default open, add the additional class in.

In other words, leave out the "in" and it will default to close. http://jsfiddle.net/JBRh7/

Comment: The requester is asking how to have it not open by default. By default the sample code on Twitter includes the "in" class which is why it shows by default. So the requester just needs to remove the "in" from the class name.

Comment: Best answer on here. Easy, simple, and perfect fix.

Comment: This should be top comment!

Comment: Yeah, this still stands, and should probably be marked the accepted answer. Saves some scrolling / hunting :)

Comment: Simplest and most logical answer. The correct way, clearly.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to close all collapsed on page load:

In class `collapse in` replace it to class `collapse`.

```
id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse **in**" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
```

Update to:

```
id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
```

Answer (score 11):

Change

```
class="accordion-body collapse in"
```

TO

```
class="accordion-body collapse"
```

On your **collapseOne** **DIV**

Answer (score 9):

If you want the [accordion](/questions/tagged/accordion) to [collapse](/questions/tagged/collapse) initially you can do so with pre-existing [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) definitions, javascript is unnecessary.

Adding the class `collapsed` to the anchor or handle which will be the click target for users to [toggle](/questions/tagged/toggle) them open/closed.  Also, remove the `in` class from the collapsing container.

Bootstrap also provides a couple of optional specifications which can be passed by adding `data-parent=""` and `data-toggle=""`

- `data-parent` accepts a selector and specifies that all collapsible elements which are siblings of the data-parent will be toggled in unison.
- `data-toggle` accepts a boolean `true` or `false` and sets invocation on the collapsible element.

---

### Example Scenarios:

➤ **Will load collapsed**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Title
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Details
```

➤ **Will load expanded**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Title
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Details
```

➤  **Will load expanded**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Title
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Details
```

In the 3rd example, the accordion will default to being expanded regardless of the fact that the `collapsed` class is specified because the `in` class on the container will receive more weight.

---

If you do want to trigger the accordion via Javascript you only have to call the method `collapse()` along with the appropriate id or class selector which targets the collapsible element.

`collapse()` also accepts the same options as can be added to the markup.  `data-parent` and `data-toggle`

Comment: this is really useful for debugging my accordions that were opened and closed based on localStorage -.- thanks! +1

Answer (score 7):

you're missing the class 'in' on accordion-body divs for Menu2 and Menu3

each of your accordion-body divs needs to have `class="accordion-body collapse in"`. Right now, a couple of them just have `class="accordion-body collapse"`

http://jsfiddle.net/fcJJT/

Comment: Thank you.  I'm noticing that everything still starts fully uncollapsed before collapsing straightaway without user input.  Do you know how I remove this initial uncollapsing effect?

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  I'm pretty new to this stuff myself

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the option `toggle: false` to the collapse statement to have all elements of the accordion hidden on load, like so:

```
$('.collapse').collapse({
    toggle: false
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gqe7g/9/

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just omitting 'in' class doesn't help at least when using JavaScrip API is required. Without `toggle: false` it executes this code: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/collapse.js#L29 (options.toggle is true by default) and it shows hiddent content.

Answer (score 2):

this is what i use for my accordian. it starts off fully closed.
you want

```
 active: false;//this does the trick
```

full:

```
<div id="accordian_div">
    <h1>first</h1>
        <div>
            put something here
        </div>
    <h1>second</h1>
        <div>
            put something here
        </div>
    <h1>third</h1>
        <div>
            put something here
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordian_div").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            clearStyle: true
        });
      });
</script>
```

Not familiar with bottstrap but this seems a bit cleaner than all the classes you have to deal with and works smoothly.

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery. I have bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `.in` class from `.panel-collapse` in "collapseOne". (Bootstrap v3.3.7)

Answer (score 1):

Use the hide method that Bootstrap provides,

```
$('.collapse').collapse('hide')
```

Demo at http://thefanciful.com. My information is hidden on load, and activates when the button is pushed. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery**, This worked for me having ALL containers **collapsed** at page load

Adding `{active: false}` and must have `collapsible` enabled of course

```
  $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
      $(".selector").accordion();
  });
```

Comment: .accordion() is not part of bootstrap, but jquery.ui a.f.a.i.k.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

       $('#collapseOne').collapse("hide");
    });      

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old discussion, but here are two more solutions that worked:

1) Add

a class of `aria-expanded="true"`
inside this link:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"...></a>
```

2) In case you're using panels (like below)

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse out collapse in" style="height: auto;">
```

changing `collapse in` to `collapse out` will also do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be a slightly hacky way but I added custom css:

`.elementor-accordion-item:first-child {
    display: none;
}`

and then duplicated the first item on the list, the great thing with this is if you have multiple accordions on the page or site you only need to do this once.