# Jquery accordion not collapse by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using collapse plugin provided by bootstrap
which is a jquery simple plugin

However it collapse by default, how to modify so that the collapse item is hidden by default, only when i press the header, then the item collapse and show? Thank you

[The document of the plugin, just few line so it only takes one minute](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$(".collapse").collapse()({
  toggle: false,
  show: false
  });
} );
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="alert alert-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="margin-bottom:0px;">                     
              Collapsible #1
                  </div>   
          <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-body collapse" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
               content1
           </div>
                           <div class="alert alert-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style="margin-bottom:0px;">                     
              Collapsible #2
                  </div>   
          <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-body collapse" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
               content2
           </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my accordion to load with all the menus closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419470/how-do-i-get-my-accordion-to-load-with-all-the-menus-closed)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, some things have changed. The following code accomplishes your desired functionality in Bootstrap 3

If you want the panel body to show by default:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

If you want the panel body to hide by default:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Here is an example:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

          <!- Repeat For Next Panel------->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                       xxxxxxxxxxxHERE IS THE HEADER CONTENTSxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    </a>
                </h4>
           </div>
               <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       xxxxxxxxxxxHERE IS THE BODY CONTENTSxxxxxxxxxxxx
                   </div>
               </div> 
         </div>
            <!- Repeat For Next Panel---(but change <div id="collapseTwo")--->

     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: And change href="#collapseOne"> to href="#collapseTwo">

Comment: I was getting frustrated until your post which made it clear that "in" does not mean "INvisible".

Comment: Do you have to have the class="panel panel-default"? I find if I remove that from the div, it stops auto closing. But I don't want the style of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="accordion-group collapse">
   <div class="alert alert-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="margin-bottom:0px;">                     
          Collapsible #1
   </div>   
   <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-body collapse" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
           content1
   </div>
   <div class="alert alert-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style="margin-bottom:0px;">                     
          Collapsible #2
    </div>   
    <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-body collapse" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
          content2
    </div>
</div>
```