# Bootstrap - Cant get my Accordion to stay closed on default?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a single accordion item that I am using for a read more / less link on a page.

The purpose of this is to click it to read more, and a few paragraphs will follow.

I have this working, but I need it to stay closed when the page loads, at the moment the page loads with the item open.

What can I add to fix this?

```
<div class="accordionMod panel-group">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Read More / Less</h4>
        <section class="accordion-inner panel-body">
            <p>more info.</p>
            <h4 class="title">More titles</h4>
            <p>more content</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this will work

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myAccordion" href="#collapseOne">
                Title
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myAccordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                Title
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you add the class `in` to `accordion-body collapse` it will be open by default.

Comment: This is working [2017]. Should be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you don't need an accordion, which has multiple panels, only one of which can open at a time. Instead, just use `collapse` which allows you to toggle the visibility of a section of the page.

#### Panel Visibility

From the [collapse docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse):

> The collapse plugin utilizes a few classes to handle the heavy lifting:
>
> - `.collapse` hides the content
> - `.collapse.in` shows the content
> - `.collapsing` is added when the transition starts, and removed when it finishes

Thus, to start off collapsed, just make sure your extra content has the class `collapse` and not `in`

#### Simple HTML

To use collapse, you really just need to specify a `data-toggle="collapse"` and then point the collapse to the css selector of the section you would like to toggle using `data-target`.

Here's a bare bones example that just exposes the collapsing functionality:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ReadMoreInfo" href="#">
    Read More / Less
</a>
<div id="ReadMoreInfo" class="collapse">
    <p> More Info Here </p>
</div>
```

#### HTML with Bootstrap classes

All the other bootstrap classes are just to help make the collapsible panel *look* like a collapsible panel.  I would recommend formatting them like this or doing a lot of custom CSS work.  Even if you wanted to do the CSS yourself, starting off with this template and then overriding the styles would be best.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" 
               data-target="#ReadMoreInfo"
               href="#ReadMoreInfo">
                Read More / Less
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="ReadMoreInfo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>more info.</p>
            <h4 class="title">More titles</h4>
            <p>more content</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/MD2FP/)

**Screenshot**:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `in` class did not work for me in my case(though normally it should). I was just looking for the answer to this question yesterday. I used this to make the accordion default to close:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.collapse').collapse({
     toggle: false
   });
});
```

See also this question on:

[Jquery accordion not collapse by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145101/jquery-accordion-not-collapse-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

if accordion is with icon, add collapsed class name to :

```
<a class="accordion-toggle accordion-toggle-styled collapsed" >
```

and add collapse class name to:

```
<div id="collapse0" class="panel-collaps collapse">
```

complete code is:

```
    <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion0">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="accordion-toggle accordion-toggle-styled collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion0" href="#collapse0">
                                                    Collapsible Header Text
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
</div>
                                        <div id="collapse_3_1" class="panel-collaps collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">

                                                <p> body text
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. In Bootstrap 5, edit your HTML to remove the "show" class from your first accordion item. See [Make accordion closed by default in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988776/make-accordion-closed-by-default-in-bootstrap/27989051), the answer that starts "Was recently working with Bootstrap".