# I cannot get the collapse function to work on Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have tried to make an accordion with bootstrap but for some reason when I try to use it the accordion will not expand to show the contents. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                    Filters
                    </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/recipes">All Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=your">My Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=breakfast">Breakfast Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=lunch">Lunch Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=dinner">Dinner Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Vegeterian Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Vegan Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Low Calorie Recipes</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Common solutions to similar questions I have seen online point to jquery script not being run but I have the following scripts in the following order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-popRpmFF9JQgExhfw5tZT4I9/CI5e2QcuUZPOVXb1m7qUmeR2b50u+YFEYe1wgzy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: BS 5.0.0-alpha3 is in alpha ;-) do not use this in production.

Comment: Bootstrap 5 is now in actual release, and is compatible with but no longer needs the jQuery library. And you can make ALL accordion items initially collapsed by editing your HTML to remove the "show" class from the div class attribute that also includes the class "accordion-collapse" (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988776/make-accordion-closed-by-default-in-bootstrap/27989051).

However, there seems to be no way to use JavaScript to show or collapse accordion items, possibly because this would require Promises or 'await' (Bootstrap animates showing/collapsing asynchronously).

Answer (score 2):

(bootstrap 5)

I just wrapped the collapsable sections with a `div` + `id`, then gave a `data-bs-parent` to each div that i have a `collapse` class for.

```
# radio button group
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-12 col-md-8 col-form-label">
        What is your choice ?
    </label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="myRadio" value="yes" id="msg1"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   aria-controls="msg1"
                   data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                   data-bs-target="#msg1">

            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="msg1">Msg 1</label>

            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="myRadio" value="no" id="msg2"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   aria-controls="msg2"
                   data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                   data-bs-target="#msg2">

            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="msg2">Msg 2</label>
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col" id="display_data">        <!-- id wrapping all collapsed divs -->
      <div class="alert alert-warning collapse" id="msg1" data-bs-parent="#display_data">
          <strong>Yes</strong><br>
          this is msg 1
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-warning collapse" id="msg2" data-bs-parent="#display_data">
          <strong>No</strong><br>
          this is msg 2
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ud7zcth/1/

Answer (score 1):

OP is using version 5 of Bootstrap

I added the official css & js links.
Bootstrap 5 has removed the jQuery dependency

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="accordion accordion" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                    Filters
                    </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/recipes">All Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=your">My Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=breakfast">Breakfast Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=lunch">Lunch Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/recipes?mealtype=dinner">Dinner Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Vegeterian Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Vegan Recipes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Low Calorie Recipes</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I was using the Alpha links and didn't realise the beta had been released

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML appears to be fine. As others have stated jQuery is not needed here. I see you're using the Alpha CDN, I would suggest using the beta version as it's more stable. Changing the JS to use this should be all you need to do:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed everything