# Accordion doesn't collapse

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

The following accordion code is not working properly for me.

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
           data-parent="#accordion1" href="#note1">
          Foo
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="note1">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          <pre>Foo body</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
           data-parent="#accordion1" href="#note2">
          Bar
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="note2">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          <pre>Bar body</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It displays and the items expand properly, but the items won't collapse. When I click an open item, it collapses briefly, and then expands again. I've seen this behavior on Bootstrap versions 2.1.0 and 2.1.1. Also, I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and 1.8.2 and viewing in Chrome 22.

Comment: Works fine for me. What does your head section look like? U mentioned you are using two versions of jquery, why? Also, which versions of the bootstrap js are you including? individual plugins or the plugin pack?

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine for me too on jsfiddle, but still doesn't work on my site.  I'm not using two versions simultaneously.  I just wanted people to know that I have tried it and get the same problem with two different versions of bootstrap and two different versions of JQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my accordion to load with all the menus closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419470/how-do-i-get-my-accordion-to-load-with-all-the-menus-closed)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I had accidentally included all my javascript script files twice.  Removing the duplicate fixed everything.  I don't know how common this mistake is, but if someone else has this problem in the future, then it might be helpful to have this answer rather than just deleting the question.

Comment: After and hour of debugging the Collapse class I discovered the same double load problem you had.  I'm use twitter-bootstrap-rails to include bootstrap.

Comment: We've run across the same thing via a menu that needs bootstrap.js, and then using require to reload it in the app. We worked around it by handling the accordion expand/collapse by using explicit javascript in our app rather than data annotations.

Comment: Same issue here - spent at least an hour, maybe more, debugging this only to realize that bootstrap.min.js was being included twice from two different files. I fixed that (never occurred to me until after reading this) and now it works perfectly. Thanks for making this mistake first and thinking to document it!

Comment: I had my Drupal theme requiring bootstrap and the subtheme also requiring the library, deleted the lines in `custom_theme.libraries.yml`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The problem was that I loaded jQuery **after** bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar silly problem. I forgot to add the script tags to include Bootstrap JS functionality... Make sure you include the Bootstrap CSS files ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#css)) and the JS files ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)). You actually do need both.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33748960)