# Bootstrap collapse DIV is open on DOM load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to find a solution for this but now I'm stuck. Tried the solutions found in this question: [How do I get my accordion to load with all the menus closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419470/how-do-i-get-my-accordion-to-load-with-all-the-menus-closed) (ie Trying to add `$("#facts").collapse('hide');` etcetera) But without luck.

I have a jsFiddle here to work on: http://jsfiddle.net/mwxkr/1/

My problem is that when the page loads, the collapse divs are open and when the row `$(".collapse").collapse('hide');` runs then the divs slide to closed. This looks like a bug when you open the page. I'd like the divs to start closed on page load and stay closed until a button is pressed.

Some markup:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-small" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#facts">Show facts</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-small" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more">Show more</button>
<div id="facts" class="collapse">
   <div class="contents">
     Some facts...
   </div>
</div>
<div id="more" class="collapse">
   <div class="contents">
     More facts...
   </div>
</div>
```

JS: (jQuery and bootstrap collapse.js loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: If you remove the $(".collapse").collapse('hide'); in your jsfiddle, the divs are closed without the effect when loading the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need js for that, the collapse element are automatically hidden while loading the page:

```
<div id="facts" class="collapse">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2EwN6/9/

Comment: Funny. I thought one needed to initiate the collapsible divs one way or the other, used the example from somewhere. I tried numerous solutions but not just removing the js completely.... THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

With Boostrap 4, the collapse is closed by default. If you want it to be open on page load, you can simply add the class `show`:

```
<div class="collapse show">...</div>
```

As per [Bootstrap 4 documention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/):

- `.collapse` hides content
- `.collapse.show` shows content