# accordion behavior with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to do some Bootstrap trickery and have run into a problem...

Here is the behavior I want:

I have three "lists" on my page: friends, status updates and results which appear in three columns when on a full computer screen.
However, when bootstrap shuffles these into one vertical column for other devices, it makes the list impossibly long. So, I want the full display for pc-screen 3-column size, but for smaller tablets and phones I want them to collapse into just the headings with Bootstrap's accordion classes.

It seems though, that these have to be manually clicked to shrink them down to the headings. I tried adding the following classes to automatically shrink or expand the accordion according to the screen size,

" hidden-xs hidden-sm"

It so nearly works!

Without the above classes, all of the accordion stuff works manually, shrinking or expanding by clicking on the accordion header.
However, when I add the above classes into line 11 of the attached fiddle, 
the column hides correctly at smaller sizes, but now the accordion doesn't work.

Here's the fiddle without the above classes added:

http://jsfiddle.net/grooble/Nykx6/5/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseStatus">
          Status
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>      
    <div id="collapseStatus" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="doNews">
            <p>
                However, a potential takeover 
                blah, blah, blah...
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: This may be worth a read? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826362/bootstrap-collapse-accordion-default-expand-collapse

Comment: Thanks davidpauljunior. Yes, I saw that too. It might be the way I have to go. I was hoping there was a way to do this just with Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you basically want (from your example) to have your accordion shrinked (collapsed) by default? If it is the case:

replace (remove the "in" class):

```
<div id="collapseStatus" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

by

```
<div id="collapseStatus" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

cf jsFiddle: [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mjarro/Nykx6/8/) http://jsfiddle.net/mjarro/Nykx6/8/

Comment: not quite, I want it expanded for large screens and collapsed for small, while also retaining the click expand/collapse functionality of accordion.

Comment: Ok I did an update: http://jsfiddle.net/mjarro/Nykx6/10/ , try to resize your Window and re Run the code you will see it expand if the window is superior to 430 and collapsed if inferior.
If it does the fix I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actually the link in @davidpauljunior 's comment above has a link to a fiddle that works (you just have to change the cutoff size from 768 to something smaller so you can see the change on the small fiddle window.)